# Showing convexity of a function that uses column sums

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Let $A\equiv\left\{ a_{sk}\right\} $ be a strictly substochastic $N \times N$
matrix (i.e., $a_{ij}\geq0$ and $\sum_{i}a_{ij}<1,\forall i$), let
$D(\exp(x))$ be the $N \times N$ diagonal matrix formed from vector $\exp(x)=(\exp(x_1),...,\exp(x_N)$ with
$x_{i}\leq 0,\forall i$, and
let $W(x)=\left(I-A\cdot D(\exp(x))\right)^{-1}$. Numerically it seems
that the function $\sum_{i}w_{ij}(x)$
is logarithmically convex for any $j$. One approach to show this is to show that
the Hessian is positive definite, but that seems hard. Any suggestions
for an alternative approach?

The result is easy to show in the case in which $A$ is a diagonal matrix.

It would be sufficient to show that $w_{ij}(x)$ is logarithmically convex for any $ij$, but I haven't checked this numerically.

Comment: My two cents: (a) The pre-factor $\sum_i w_{ij}(\iota)$ is redundant for the question and (b) The claim is true in the one-dimensional case.

Comment: You are right on (a). I have simplified the question accordingly.

Comment: And you are of course right on (b).

Comment: For the same reason, and more broadly, it is also true in the case in which the $A$ matrix is a diagonal matrix.